# Saving email to the directory with specified file name is not working in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I am trying to follow the approach suggested in a [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-System-Net-Mail-MailM) by Allan Eagle in code-project. This same approach was working fine up until `.NET Core 3.1`, but not with `.NET 5.0` . Here is the save method I created,

```
 private void Save(MailMessage message, string filePath)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        var mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructors(bindingFlags)[0];
            var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { fileStream });//<-- This line throws error saying parameter mismatch
            var sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", bindingFlags);
            sendMethod.Invoke(message, bindingFlags, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);
            var closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", bindingFlags);
            closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, bindingFlags, null, new object[] { }, null);
        }
    }
```

I checked all the available underlying invoke methods and tried working with them passing needed parameters but non of them worked for me.

Error Message: "Parameter count mismatch."
Inner Exception: null
Stack Trace:

```
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at..//user written line info
```

Any help to solve this issue or new approach to achieve same thing using `System.Net.Mail` will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The [`MailWriter` constructor now takes 2 parameters](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Mail/System/Net/Mail/MailWriter.cs,18). Don't use reflection to access internal types like this: they can and **will** break between even minor releases

Comment: Thank you @canton7 for your response and a valuable suggestion.

Comment: That article is extremely old and simply unusable in 2020. Despite the date, it was written in 2009 and actually *stopped working in 2014* when one of the internal methods changed signature. Microsoft [warns pretty strongly that SmptClient is deprecated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks) in the class's documentation and recommends using MailKit instead ***Important**
We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead*

Comment: So, what are you trying to do? Forget the obsolete SmtpClient and `System.Net.Mail`. Whatever it is you want to do, there are better ways. Precisely because `System.Net.Mail` is obsolete, `MailMessage` and `MailWriter` can't handle signed, secure, rich or multipart messages

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos for the well explained answer. Now, this is something worth of discussing with my team and switching to the new more powerful library like MailKit, as you suggested in the answer.

Comment: Despite being aware of the fact that Microsoft warned it for deprecation and there was some changes with internal methods back in days, I still posted this on stack because 'System.Net.Mail' is used across multiples projects and it also avoids necessity of using one extra external library.  And, I believe, getting ideas from expert on the stack is always a good thing. So, is this question worthy of getting downvote? Anyway, Upvotes and Downvotes are equally. Just wondering If I missed anything on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this article is obsolete in 2020. Despite the date, it was actually written in 2009 and stopped working in 2014, when some of the internal methods changed signature. In any case, the `System.Net.Mail` namespace shouldn't be used because, as Microsoft strongly warns:

> **Important**

> We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or other libraries instead. For more information, see [SmtpClient shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) on GitHub.

MailKit (or rather the MimeKit library it's built upon) already supports saving and loading Mail messages. From [Q: How do I save messages?](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SaveMessages) the answer is a simple:

```
message.WriteTo("message.eml");
```

You can use MailKit's POP3 or IMAP4 clients to retrieve messages. The [DownloadMessages](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/Pop3Examples.cs#L40) example show how to download messages from GMail and save them:

```
        using (var client = new Pop3Client (new ProtocolLogger ("pop3.log"))) {
            client.Connect ("pop.gmail.com", 995, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

            client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++) {
                var message = client.GetMessage (i);

                // write the message to a file
                message.WriteTo (string.Format ("{0}.msg", i));

                // mark the message for deletion
                client.DeleteMessage (i);
            }

            client.Disconnect (true);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To explicitly give you an answer based on first comment,

```
var encodeForTransport = false;
var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { fileStream, encodeForTransport  });
```